# time series plot with strings in axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, axis-labels

I have a small time series of the form

```
                    created    current_page
0  2020-02-29T19:26:00.000Z        SOMMARIO
1  2020-02-29T19:25:00.000Z  DATI PERSONALI
2  2020-02-29T19:25:00.000Z    OFFERTA FULL
3  2020-02-29T19:24:00.000Z       DATI BENE
4  2020-02-29T19:23:00.000Z        HOMEPAGE
```

How could I plot it and get in the x-axis the dates in the "created" column and in the y-axis the "current page" elements?
So far I have tried to use the label encoder for the y-axis values, but when I do that, also in the x-axis appear floating numbers instead of the dates. My code is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
series["current_page"] = le.fit_transform(series["current_page"].values)
series.plot()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

and I get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have checked on my local machine and it worked:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# data
created = ["2020-02-29T19:26:00.000Z", 
           "2020-02-29T19:25:00.000Z", 
           "2020-02-29T19:25:00.000Z", 
           "2020-02-29T19:24:00.000Z",
           "2020-02-29T19:23:00.000Z"]

current_page = ["SOMMARIO", "DATI PERSONALI", "OFFERTA FULL", "DATI BENE", "HOMEPAGE"]

# create df from data
df = pd.DataFrame([created, current_page], ["created", "current_page"]).T

# convert to datetime
df["created"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created"])

# enconde data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df["current_page"] = le.fit_transform(df["current_page"].values)

# separte x and y
x = df["created"]
y = df["current_page"]

# plot data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
```